# SecurityException: android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS missing for bluetooth access

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-bluetooth

Facing this issue on non system app when attempting to do: "BluetoothAdapter::getProfileProxy". Observed only on android 8.1 but not reproducible.

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: query intent receivers: Neither user 15010171 nor current process has android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS.
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2021)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1967)
at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.queryIntentServices(IPackageManager.java:4830)
at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.queryIntentServicesAsUser(ApplicationPackageManager.java:1255)
at android.content.Intent.resolveSystemServiceAsUser(Intent.java:8365)
at android.bluetooth.BluetoothA2dp.doBind(BluetoothA2dp.java:432)
at android.bluetooth.BluetoothA2dp.<init>(BluetoothA2dp.java:405)
at android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.getProfileProxy(BluetoothAdapter.java:3034)
```

Questions:

- Why this permission "INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS" is coming as an issue. (we check for bluetooth permission)
- As per https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothA2dp.java

  ```
  boolean doBind() {
  Intent intent = new Intent(IBluetoothA2dp.class.getName());
  ComponentName comp = intent.resolveSystemService(mContext.getPackageManager(), 0);
  intent.setComponent(comp); ...
  ```

  It looks like the permission issue is somewhere else - in some system service.

Wondering if someone can explain the issue.

Comment: It would appear you are trying to modify settings or values that are applicable to more than the signed in user on the Android device. Android supports multiple users. So I don't know what exactly you are encountering without seeing the exact line of code that is causing the issue.  But my proclivity would be to look at global settings that you are touching for bluetooth and file pathways that you are using.

Comment: as mentioned m invoking BluetoothAdapter::getProfileProxy.. not changing any settings

Comment: Right, but you are accessing it as a service. So is your service running on the device regardless of the user? If I had to guess, I would assume you are accessing the getProfileProxy from a background service and that it is attempting to use the service credentials to access it and being rejected as it is user 15010171 or the process. I'm assuming if you accessed it outside of the service in your app, like if it was passed into the bind routine, it would probably function. So your question is probably more "how to access getProfileProxy" from a background service. But I could be wrong.

Comment: m not accessing it as service.. the code inside BluetoothAdapter::getProfileProxy seems to find IBluetoothA2dp via intent.resolveSystemService - which is android's code.
I'm invoking BluetoothAdapter::getProfileProxy from normal app - usually after the app has just started